# Rails 6 w/Webpacker - Host URL / Reverse Proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, webpack

I'm going to try and ask this as simple and clear as possible. Trying to include all relevant specs and details. Hopefully, in the end, this will help someone. I have a small **Rails 6** app using **Webpacker**. Everything is working perfectly in Development and Staging environments. It's in Production where things get murky.

My **Rails 6** app/server has the URL/hostname, for example, https://my.rails.app.com . However, the infrastructure that's been set up for this app goes through a reverse proxy. So the actual public-facing URL is different due to the proxy, for example, https://hello.world.com/my/rails.

I have Nginx running and pointed to the proxy. Here's the config. Might be helpful.

```
upstream my.rails.app.com  {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

Server {
 listen 443 SSL
 server_name: hello.world.com/my/rails
 SSL cert ...
 ...
 }

location / {
  proxy_pass        http://my.rails.app.com;
  proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto: https;
  proxy_bind $server_addr;
}
```

The first thing I noticed when testing on Production was none of the assets (images, JS, CSS) were not loading. I was able to fix this by adding this to **environment/production.rb**

```
config.relative_url_root = "/my/rails"
```

The next thing that was noticed, the `link_to` helper method was not working. They were only getting the hostname (hello.world.com), not the full-path (hello.world.com/my/rails). I fixed this by adding an ENV variable with the path.

```
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/my/rails"
```

My `link_to` now looks like this:

```
link_to "Example", "#{ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']}" + some_path
```

*The one thing I can't get working is Webpacker.* When I "Show Page Source" from a browser, I see several 404 errors from Webpacker trying to load assets. When "Show Page Source" I see this:

```
https://hello.world.com/packs/media/compiled asset ... (404 error)
```

It's **missing** the **"/my/rails"** directory path.

My questions are the following:

- How do I tell Rails/Webpacker to look beyond the base URL and use the full path? "https://hello.world.com/my/rails"?
- Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'm not happy with using ENV variables in the link_to helpers. It feels dirty. I'm open and all ears. :)
- I thought to add a `scope` to my routes file, thinking it would solve the path problem, which by the way did not work. Here's an example: `scope ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] do SomeRoute SomeOtherRoute end` In testing the URL's looked correct, but would go to a 404 page. Not really sure why...

Any help would be very much welcomed. Thanks and hopefully this all makes sense.